# wrong order of elements in response message for complex types in the wsdl

Tags: xsd, wsdl, axis

I have a wsdl file generated by using axis+ant+jboss.

SuperClass ActionInfo wsdl definition:

Code:

```
<complexType abstract="true" name="ActionInfo">
 <sequence>
  <element name="configUnitId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="configUnitType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="desc" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="errorCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
  <element name="id" nillable="true" type="tns2:ResourceIdentityInfo"/>
  <element name="result" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="status" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 </sequence>
</complexType>
```

SubClass PushActionInfo wsdl definition:

Code:

```
<complexType name="PushActionInfo">
<complexContent>
 <extension base="tns19:ActionInfo">
  <sequence>
   <element name="activationMethod" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="activationRequired" type="xsd:boolean"/>
   <element name="binaryContent" type="xsd:boolean"/>
   <element name="category" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="contentType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="destinationName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="dynamic" type="xsd:boolean"/>
   <element name="maskableContent" nillable="true" type="tns2:MaskableContentInfo"/>
   <element name="payloadName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="postOps" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string"/>
   <element name="pushMechanism" type="xsd:int"/>
   <element name="rollback" type="xsd:boolean"/>
   <element name="snmpEnabled" type="xsd:boolean"/>
  </sequence>
 </extension>
 </complexContent>
 </complexType>
```

Based on the WSDL definition, it is expected that the ActionInfo sequence attributes occur before the PushActionInfo attributes.  In this case, they are commingled. And the result is :

Code:

```
PushActionInfo (current)
activationMethod
activationRequired
binaryContent
category
configUnitId – extension of ActionInfo
configUnitType - extension of ActionInfo
contentType
desc - extension of ActionInfo
destinationName
dynamic
errorCode - extension of ActionInfo
id - extension
maskableContent
payloadName
postOps
pushMechanism
result - extension of ActionInfo
rollback
snmpEnabled
status - extension of ActionInfo
```

But my expectation is:

Code:

```
configUnitId – extension of ActionInfo
configUnitType - extension of ActionInfo
desc - extension of ActionInfo
errorCode - extension of ActionInfo
result - extension of ActionInfo
status - extension of ActionInfo
activationMethod
activationRequired
binaryContent
category
contentType
destinationName
dynamic
id - extension
maskableContent
payloadName
postOps
pushMechanism
rollback
snmpEnabled
```

This Link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2677 describes the issue with Axis.

So I have tried with JbossWS+JAXB to generate a different wsdl file. Both are giving the response alphabetically. Is there any way to change the order of the response element?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a `propOrder` on the `@XmlType` annotation to specify the order of elements.

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"ID", "firstName", "lastName"})
public class Customer {
   ..
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/jaxbs-xmltransient-and-property-order.html

Comment: I know i am responding to the old thread.. But propOrder is not working for me.  Do i need to use any special in order utilize jaxb functionality?

Comment: @priceline - Could you post a new question for the issue you are seeing?